# C++ compilation error when adding windows.h

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I need to write small tool in C++ 
I've never used C++ as programming language before (I have couple years of Java dev experience) and .NET

I've started a new project in VS , when I am adding in my Header file of my class

`#include <windows.h>` I am getting the following error:

> Error  1   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'  c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\servprov.h    96  1   CppLog

For now my class even doesn't have any real functions and looks like

```
in header
class TheTool
{
   public :
     void Foo();
};

in cpp

void TheTool::Foo(){};
```

and the project doesn't get compiled.

plz any suggestions ? Maybe a compiler doen't set up good ?

this is how the Header file looks like

```
#pragma once

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>

//#include <Windows.h>
//#include <winuser.h>
//#include <windowsx.h>
//#include <time.h>

class TheTool
{
   public :
    void Foo();
};
```

When I am uncommenting the include  I am starting to get this compilation error.

BTW , how can i know the compiller setting ?

Comment: You need to describe your compilation environment.

Comment: Which Visual Studio version do you use? What kind of project did you create?

Comment: The semicolon after `void TheTool::Foo(){}` is unnecessary, I've had compilers throw warnings about that sort of thing, but some may not handle it properly.

Comment: Wait is *your* header called "windows.h"? Windows.h is the Win32 API header, you should name it something else

Comment: No , my Header is called TheTool.h

Comment: I am using VS 2010 and project type is WIN32 console application

Comment: Which line gives the error? Also, including `windows.h` will include `winuser.h` automatically. I remember hearing somewhere that `windows.h` should be the first file included, if that changes anything.

Comment: On a side note, why `stdio.h` instead of `cstdio`?

Comment: This line is giving the error 
typedef /* [unique] */  __RPC_unique_pointer IServiceProvider *LPSERVICEPROVIDER;

in file servprov.h

Comment: Just now created empty project in VS 2010 (win 32 console app) and added #include <windows.h> , giving the compilation error

Comment: I've switched to Visual studio 2008 , it works there.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. What settings do you use with the application wizard (when you create the new project)? Application type? Add common header files (ATL/MFC)? Precompiled headers?

Comment: @user - Have you checked the stdafx.h header in your project? Bet it already includes all the Windows headers.

Comment: You shouldn't be including stdafx.h from inside a header file.  That precompiled header include file should be the first thing (excluding comments) inside a source file.